# Why do we have to use schema.path when adding an unique index?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Why do we have to add the second line if the index has been declared in the first line?

```
var schema = new Schema({ name: { type: String, unique: true }});
>> schema.path('name').index({ unique: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess to use the newer 'createIndexes' function instead of the older (and less potentially less performant), deprecated 'ensureIndex' function:

Using `{ unique: true }`, you'll get this error message:

> (node:2924) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated.
>   Use createIndexes instead.

If you use the explicit declaration of indexes, not only does your code get cleaner and easier to read, but also the warning will go away. If you use the explicit declaration, you can also leave out the { unique: true } statement, since it'll probably be ignored anyways.

Comment: I used `"useCreateIndex": true` to hide deprecation. So `schema.path('name').index({ unique: true });` that is an explicit declaration?

Comment: Yeah, I believe that this should be the same then!